# Receiving the correct length of data over serial

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, windows, serialization

Originally, I am using putty to display the output of my embedded device. However, I want to manipulate the data as I receive it, thus I used python to connect to the port(w timeout 0). All the C code does is print the buffer (lets say file length of size = 22112 bytes) as following:

```
for (x = 0; x < size; x++) {
    printf("%x", buffer[x]);
}

printf("\r\n");
```

The python code just reads the data as a line since I end the C code with a new  line after the loop:

```
ser_bytes = ser.readline()    
print(len(ser_bytes))
```

But python prints the length to be 34742 when it should be 22112. As you may have noticed, I print the values in hex, other formats give other values.

So what is the correct way to receive the data to get the correct size?
And is there any other way to do this?

**UPDATE:**
Currently I am using:

```
write(1, fileBuffer, size);
```

To write the raw data, but Python STILL does not receive all the data. Out of 22112, only around 8000 is received. Printing to Putty shows the correct number of data though.

For some visuals, this is the end of the file (around 8000 bytes) which is stored by python when the data is received over serial.

[image: This is the file saved by python which misses some data]

This is the original file itself (directly from the SD card). I highlighted where the data stops exactly.

[image: Here we can see how the data is not missing]
**UPDATE:**

The problem seems to be a buffer issue. Since I am running on windows, I used the following to increase the buffer size:

```
ser.set_buffer_size(rx_size = 25000, tx_size = 25000)
```

`ser.inWaiting()`, shows a total of 22208 in the buffer when it should be 22112. I read it and store it anyways using `ser.read(ser.inWaiting())`. To see where the extra bytes are coming from, I print two lines from the original file and from the file after it is received over serial: 
[image]

There seems to be an 'extra' carriage return in the file over serial. Where did it come from?

Comment: But you "send" the data as *text* which means there might be more data transferred. Remember that a single byte will need *two* hexadecimal digits.

Comment: Is there another way to send it in its original form?

Comment: You can always write the raw data as-is over the serial port. But then the receiver can't treat it as text (it can't use `readline` for example). One way is to first send the size as a fixed-length buffer, the receiver reads this fixed-length buffer and converts it to an integer. Then the receiver knows exactly how many bytes to read. Depending on system I recommend you use `write` on the C side, otherwise `fwrite` to `stdout`.

Comment: What is the type of buffer ? and what are you trying to transfer ?

Comment: @Sylvaus unsigned char, image data from the SD card of the embedded device

Comment: On the C side consider using the format `"%02x"` to guarantee two hex bytes per data byte.  With plain `%x` the printer may only produce one byte for small data values.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I tried writing the raw value (see update) but python receives around half of it, any ideas? Ty

Comment: @Sarahcartenz That's probably because you still use `readline` in the Python code? That will stop when it sees a "newline" in the data it reads. Arbitrary binary data could contain a "newline" without it being an actual newline. You need to change the receiving code to read raw data as well.

Comment: @stovfl See Sarah's comment above.

Comment: @Sarahcartenz By the way, is it *exactly* `8000`? Not e.g. `8192`? What happens if you send a different file, does it also stop early, after how many bytes? The same amount? *Exactly* the same amount? Then it seems to be a buffering issue.

Comment: @stovfl <class 'bytes'>
b'\xff\xd8\xff\xdb\x00\x84\x00\r\t\t\x0b\r\n\x08\r\x0b'

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude indeed it is, but I got another problem after increasing the size (see update). I dont think my C code is the source (its a plain write). In the python, im just calling f.write(ser_bytes) to write to a file directly. Maybe the OS?

Comment: @Sarahcartenz ***using putty to display the output***: Is putty able to display hex as well to compare with the Python `print(ser_bytes[:16])`?

Comment: @stovfl if I send the raw value using "write" then not really. Putty shows a mixture of gibberish. using printf shows comparable values. Based on the update there is always an extra carriage for some reason

Comment: What makes you think, these *`\r`* **is not** part of your data? Your output shows **doubled data** one with and one without `\r`, is this expected?

Comment: @stovfl its not doubled data, the first line shows the data from the SD card, the 2nd shows the data from the SD sent over serial to show the difference. Same for the next 2 lines. My data in C prints and sends the size 22112, the data on python receives 22208. In the original data, \r doesn't exist and its appended before \n for some reason. It makes me think it has something to do with the serial communication.

Comment: OK, `\n` is Unix mode and `\r\n` is *Windows* mode. This may explain the length differences.